# response redirect vs http request get response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

what I am trying to do is to link and ASP application with an MVC application. Right now the MVC application is contained in a frame of my ASP application. What I want to do is so that when I click my logout button for my ASP application the log out method for the MVC application is also called.

Right now my logout page looks like this:

```
    <% Dim xmlhttp, cookie
      'xmlHttp makes and async call to a POST method which finishes the ASP application session    
       Session.Abandon     
      'I execute methods to set the cookie value to an empty string
    %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Logout</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
<form method="POST" action="/end_MVC_Application.aspx">  
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The end_MVC_Application page is actually empty:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="end_MVC_Application.aspx.cs" Inherits="end_MVC_Application" %>
```

But the code behind has the following logic. What I am doing here is calling the method to logout the MVC application by redirecting the page to call on the logout MVC specific method. Notice that the Logout method does not return a view on the MVC because I do not need one.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = "http:localhost/MyController/Logout";
    Response.Redirect(url,true);            
}
```

This works fine, the MVC application is actually logging out. However I need to redirect to the actual login page of the ASP application. I have tried different ways but none seem to work. I have tried to change the Response.Redirect of the previous method to this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http:localhost/MyController/Logout";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('http://localhost/login.asp" + "', '_top')");
        Response.Write("</script>");
    }
```

This way I have verified that the logout method on the MVC application is being called and that the application is being redirected to the login page. HOWEVER this does not closes the MVC application even though the logout method is being called. 
I do not understand why the Response.Redirect behaves differently. I am guessing it has something to do with the "true" boolean value which ends the response but I do not understand.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this. Greetings, Luis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login ticket is a cookie stored on the client browser. The redirect to logout works because it is telling the client browser to redirect with a http 302 response and then your logout code expires the cookie.

In your second attempt you are making a request using WebRequest on the server side, the client knows nothing about this and still have a valid login cookie stored.

Perhaps your logout controller can take a ReturnUrl parameter and use that url to redirect ?

```
/MyController/Logout?ReturnUrl=/login.aspx
```